# Create geotools MultiPoint from java Collection

Tags: geotools, multipoint

I would like to create a GeoJSON containing a `MultiPoint` from a list of WGS coordinates in my custom format (say `MyLonLat`). I wanted to use geotools library to simplify this, but I can't find a nice and easy way to do this. One can create a `MultiPoint` from `Coordinate[]` or `Point[]` or `CoordinateSequence`, but not regular Java `Collection`, like `List`.

I found that `GeometryFactory` has method `toGeometryArray`, which can convert my list into `Geometry[]` (like `Point[]`). The problem is, that `Point` is not as simple a `Coordinate` so converting `MyLonLat` to `Point` requires implementing methods that I don't need.

Comment: Why not just make `MyLonLat` extend `Point`? or `Coordinate`?

Comment: It's a closed class

Answer (score 0):

The obvious way to solve this is to make your `MyLatLon` class extend `Point` with something like this:

```
public class BuildMultiPoints {
  static GeometryFactory GF = new GeometryFactory();
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    BuildMultiPoints me = new BuildMultiPoints();
    ArrayList<MyLonLat> points = new ArrayList<>();
    MyLonLat myLonLat = me.new MyLonLat(90.0, 0.0);
    points.add(myLonLat);
    points.add(me.new MyLonLat(50.0, 50.0));
    
    MultiPoint mp = GF.createMultiPoint(points.toArray(new MyLonLat[] {}));
    System.out.println(mp);
  }

  public class MyLonLat extends Point {
    public MyLonLat(double lat, double lon) {
      super(CoordinateArraySequenceFactory.instance().create(new Coordinate[] { new Coordinate(lat, lon) }), GF);
    }

    public MyLonLat(CoordinateSequence coordinates, GeometryFactory factory) {
      super(coordinates, factory);

    }

  }
}
```

If you are unable to do that then the next best option would be to store a `Point` inside the `MyLonLat` and delegate to that. Then you can go through the list extracting the points to build your multipoint.

Comment: I am sorry, but all these answers are of little use from the same reason: MyLonLat is closed (it's a part of some API) which means, it can't be extended from Point (or anything else), or can't store Point. I am really surprised that authors of geotools made these classes so  cumbersome to use. The fact that one can't initiate them from standard containers is a real shame.

Comment: It's hard to think of a reason why anyone would want to do what you are doing, in fact in 20+ years you are the first person who wants to, so feel free to add some code to do it.

Comment: Is it really? Let me help you with that: you have a library that manipulates geodetic data in its own custom format and now you want to store it in a geojson for visualization using other tools. Is that so uncommon? Take any decent library there is - mapping data between various formats is always a typical usecase. It is hard for me to believe that in 20+ years you had no need for this. I had it in my first days of using geotools.

Comment: feel free to use any of those other libraries, I will send you a full refund of your GeoTools license fee.

Comment: I was not talking about geodetic libaries, but ANY libraries. So yes, I am using them for other purposes, but they will not help me with this specific problem of storing my data as GeoJSON. I was hoping geotools will help, but I guess it was too much to ask.

Comment: it sounds like you need to convert your incoming data into features and then serialise them through the geojson datastore

Comment: I had a brief look at: https://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/tutorial/feature/csv2shp.html and yes, it looks like it is similar to my usecase: I create Features (some WGS points) on the fly and then serialize them as a single MultiPoint. Not sure how to do it yet, but at least gives me some hope.